# STM32 Hardfault when calling any C-function

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, stm32

Trying to learn more about ARM chips and after a successful blinky using assembly I now want to mix C and Assembly functions. However, any C-function I call causes a Hardfault. I think i'm missing something obvious.

I compile using gcc and these flags

```
-c -g -ggdb -Wall --specs=nosys.specs
```

I use the following libc.a libgcc.a libraries when linking

```
-L/usr/local/gnu-arm/arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/softfp -lc -L/usr/local/gnu-arm/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/thumb/v7e-m+fp/softfp
```

From the objdump, this is where the hardfault happens:

```
 80004d4:   d3fb        bcc.n   80004ce <FillZerobss>
 80004d6:   f7ff ff09   bl  80002ec <SystemInit>
```

The chip raises a hardfault when the abobe bl is exceuted

Here is the first lines of the SystemInit function

```
080002ec <SystemInit>:
80002ec:    e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
80002f0:    e28db000    add fp, sp, #0, 0
80002f4:    e59f3014    ldr r3, [pc, #20]   ; 8000310 <SystemInit+0x24>
80002f8:    e3a02302    mov r2, #134217728  ; 0x8000000
80002fc:    e5832008    str r2, [r3, #8]
8000300:    e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
```

Instead of 080002ec I end up at:

```
08000298 <HardFault_Handler>
```

I think I'm missing something quite obvious but can't see it. Any help or pointers would be appriciated.

Comment: Shouldn't this assemble to a `blx` if you call an ARM (i.e. non thumb) function?  I wonder if this is a problem of lacking thumb interwork.  Please make a [mcve] so I can debug this and try to find a solution?

Comment: Thanks for checking! Good point about blx, did not resolve the issue though. I will look into if I'm missing compiler flags for gcc. Will work on a minimal example.

Comment: any reason of not using something more human friendly? in 21st century there is no need of using objdump do see what is happening.

Comment: I'm using GDB for debugging. objdump was easier to copy/paste from though. 

edit: I'm just a hobbyist though, I'm sure there are lots of tools i'm simply not aware of :)

Comment: @user13424266 You should not need to use `blx` yourself.  The linker should patch this automatically.  Please make a [mcve] so I can investigate what is going on.  It's sadly not possible to debug this any further seeing just the excerpts you have posted.

Comment: I think this is just a simple misconfiguration in your project. Do you use makefile ? If yes please share it. 
Personally as hobbyist I would recommend you using an IDE like STM32cubeIDE. Then If you can launch your code you will be able to remove the IDE by trying to configure it yourself.

Comment: install any IDE. Atollic studio for example (nice set of very handy plugins) See everything in the human friendly form. command line debugging is a torture and does not teach anything.

Comment: @P__J__ for your utopia to exist someone has to know how things work, 21st century or not, you could try to be helpful since it is those folks that make it seem like this knowledge and these tools arent necessary to/for you.

Comment: based on some clues my guess is you are running on a cortex-m which cannot run arm instructions only thumb instructions and which thumb instructions depends on the chip and core.  What chip/core is this.

Comment: What part(s) did you write in assembly?  Please show a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.  in this case a dozen lines of code across two files should be more than enough

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever to use an IDE nor set of libraries, you can be one of the folks that creates these environments for others who have no desire to know how things work, you are on the right track, keep up the good work.

Comment: Thanks for everyones help and pointing me in the right direction. I added -mthumb -mthumb-interwork to GCC and it now works as expected

Comment: @old_timer programming ARMs in assembler using vi and debugging with command line gdb has no educational value.

Comment: @P__J__  This question is a real-world professional problem that happens to folks on a daily basis, without these skills folks like this would be stuck indefinitely rather than it being a few seconds to see the problem.  Let them learn something...I like to think this site is about education as well as just getting your bugs fixed by someone else.  I am sorry that you disagree.  We will continue to agree to disagree on this topic.

Comment: @fuz I just tried it out: The GNU linker does not replace the `bl` by `blx`. However, STM32 CPUs typically have Cortex-M cores, which do neither support non-thumb code nor the `blx` instruction.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Hm... I know there is a feature like that (used for thumb interwork), but I don't know how it worked exactly.

Answer (score 0):

*The comments show that the question could be fixed in the meantime. This answer collects a digest of useful comments in order to have a brief answer to the question:*

Idea (old_timer):

> based on some clues my guess is you are running on a Cortex-M, 
>   which cannot run ARM instructions only thumb instructions, 
>   and which thumb instructions depends on the chip and core.
>
> What chip/core is this?

OP (user13424266):

> Thanks for everyones help and pointing me in the right direction. I added `-mthumb -mthumb-interwork` to GCC and it now works as expected!

Confirmation (Martin Rosenau):

> @fuz I just tried it out: The GNU linker does not replace the `bl` by `blx`.
>   However, STM32 CPUs typically have Cortex-M cores, which do neither support 
>   non-thumb code nor the `blx` instruction.

Comment: I think the actual best GCC option would be `-mcpu=cortex-m3` or whatever that CPU actually is.  Thumb interworking is not needed since it can't run in ARM mode, *only* Thumb.